# Alignment of Text (TEXT having No Spaces) in DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I enter **Lengthy Text** in **Textarea** with **no spaces** and I **append** it, It **disturbs** the **Alignment** of **DIV** and Text is shown in **Single Line**. How to Control this type of Text in DIV with Fixed Width?

**Here is my DEMO :**

http://jsfiddle.net/YRKxR/29/

**Also Take a Look at this Image, Just trying to Explain my issue in better way.**

[image]

I am providing the Code here too OR Visit my JsFiddle DEMO

**Here is My HTML:**

```
<table border="0" width="500" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody class="append_data"></tbody>

<tr>
  <td> 
      <textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea>
      <p>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_more">Add More</a>
      </p>
  </td> 
</tr> 

</table>
```

**Here is CSS:**

```
#description{
    width:400px;    
}

.description_text{
    border:#333333 solid 1px;
    width:400px !important;
}
```

**Here is my JS CODE:**

```
$('.add_more').click(function()
                     {
                        var description = $('#description').val();
                        $(".append_data").append('<div class="description_text">'+description+'</div><br><br>');
                     });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be looking to wrap the text in the div:

css:

```
#description{
    width:400px;    
}

.description_text{
    border:#333333 solid 1px;
    width:400px !important;
}

.append_data{
   white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7jE9p/

Answer (score 4):

use this:

```
.description_text{
    border:#333333 solid 1px;
    width:400px !important;
    word-break:break-all; // this is the css property that would work
}
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/YRKxR/31/

Answer (score 1):

Use css

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YRKxR/30/)

Answer (score 0):

Note : This code doesn't use CSS3 property

You can update the css property for the div with Overflow. like,

```
.description_text{
    border:#333333 solid 1px;
    width:400px !important;
    overflow:auto;
    display:block;
}
```